# Is topology on $C[0,1]$ metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of all continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$, then you can induce a topology of pointwise convergence, right? First question, how will these open sets look like? My other question, is this space  metrizable? If not, why?

Comment: The seminorms inducing the topology are given by $p_t(f) := |f(t)|$, where $t\in [0,1]$. Now, you can buid up your topology by defining the subbasis and then the basis.

Comment: Is it possible to define i topology not induced by any norm in this space?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Your opening sentence suggests the question, is a topology determined by its *convergent sequences*?  Is it possible that two different topologies have the same convergent sequences?  As the rest of your Question is related to metrizability, let's note that a *metric* topology is determined by its convergent sequences, but more generally sequences are not "enough" to do this.  A related post at MathOverflow: [Is a topology determined by its convergent sequences?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36379/is-a-topology-determined-by-its-convergent-sequences)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deduce that the product of uncountably many copies of the real line \Bbb{R} is not metrizable.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813952/deduce-that-the-product-of-uncountably-many-copies-of-the-real-line-bbbr-is-n)

Comment: @XiangYu $C[0,1]$ is a non-closed proper subspace of $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$.

Comment: @FrankScience Sorry, I don't see the question clearly.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some useful results that answer this question and more general questions of the same nature.

Denote by $C_{p}(X)$ the collection of continuous functions $X\to\mathbb{R}$ with the topology of point wise convergence; define the weight $w(Y)$ of a topological space $Y$ to be the minimum cardinality of a basis; and define the character $\chi(Y):=\sup_{y}\chi(Y,y)$ of a topological space $Y$ to be the supremum over all minimal cardinalities of the neighborhood basis of $Y$, i.e. $\chi(Y,y)$ is the minimum cardinality of a neighborhood basis at $y\in Y$.

Let $Y$ then be an infinite set.

- Theorem #1: we have $|Y|=\chi(C_{p}(Y))=w(C_{p}(Y))$.
- Theorem #2: the following are equivalent for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$:
  \begin{align*}
  (i)& \;\; w(Y)\leq \kappa,\\
  (ii)&\;\; Y\;\mathrm{embeds}\;\mathrm{in}\;\mathbb{R}^{\kappa},\\
  (iii)&\;\; Y\;\mathrm{embeds}\;\mathrm{in}\;[0,1]^{\kappa}.
  \end{align*}

Now every metrizable space is first countable, so if $C_{p}(X)$ is metrizable we have by Theorem #1 that $|X|\leq \omega$. And conversely, if $X$ is countable, then by Theorem #1 we have $w(C_{p}(X))=\omega$, and Theorem #2 gives us an embedding $C_{p}(X)\to\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$, making $C_{p}(X)$ metrizable.

**Conclusion:** $C_{p}(X)$ is metrizable if and only if $X$ countable.

To your specific example, since $[0,1]$ is uncountable, then $C[0,1]$ with point wise convergence is not metrizable.

Reference to Theorems #1 and #2 is e.g. the following book: "V. Tkachuk - $C_{p}$ theory problem book of topological and function spaces", s.209 (p. 165) and s.169 (p. 142).

Answer (score 2):

The topology of point-wise convergence in $C[0,1]$ is not metrisable because [it is not first-countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179800/cx-with-the-pointwise-convergence-topology-is-not-metrizable). As for the open sets, this topology has a natural [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase) consisting of sets of the form
$$\{f\in C[0,1]\colon |f(x)|<\varepsilon\}\quad (x\in [0,1], \varepsilon > 0).$$